# How would I store JSON data in a flat file database?

Tags: php, database, json, flat-file

I need to store some data in a JSON file. I know how to use json_encode but I can't find any information on how to write the encoded data into an external file. Here's a pice of code that prints out the encoded data, but how can I write the data in a separate JSON file?

```
<?php
$array1 = array('key1' => "data1",
        'key2' => "data2",
        'key3' => "data3",
        'key4' => "data4",
        'key5' => "data5");

echo json_encode($array1);
?>
```

Comment: `file_put_contents('file.json', json_encode($array1));`?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: your question amounts to writing stuff on a file... you can't even look that up?

Comment: use PHP PDO to store it. Consider PostgreSQL with HStore to store it.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking it needed to be more complicated than "just writing stuff on a file."

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents('array1.json', json_encode($array1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fwrite(...)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

From DOCs:

```
// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
    // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
    // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
?>
```

Or just use [`file_put_contents(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
file_put_contents($filname, $data);
```